# Error trying to upload an image when there is none on the db

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I created a function to upload images to my db table, but it gives me an error when the image field in the table is empty, here's the code:

```
$consulta_img = "SELECT `poster`, `screenshot1`, `screenshot2`, `screenshot3`, `screenshot4`, `screenshot5`, `screenshot6`, `screenshot7`, `screenshot8` FROM `serie` WHERE `id`='$_POST[id_editar]'";
$imagenes = mysql_query ($consulta_img);
$imagen = mysql_fetch_array($imagenes);


function actualizar_imagen($imagen_cargada){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    if($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'] != ""){
        global $imagen;
        $imagen_actual = $imagen[$imagen_cargada];
        unlink("../publico/img/".$imagen_actual);
        $imagen_final = $fecha . $_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['tmp_name'], '../publico/img/' . $imagen_final);
    }else{
        $imagen_final = $fecha . $_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['tmp_name'], '../publico/img/' . $imagen_final);
    }
    return $imagen_final;
}
```

The error i'm getting back is this:

```
 Warning: unlink(../publico/img/2013_11_16_15_56_53_CIMG1884.JPG) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\dejavu\administrador\editar.php on line 19
```

And it's completely logical, that image does not exist, but that means that the else is not working, and I can't figure out why.

---

Here is the UPDATE query part:

```
$campo = $_GET['img_borrar'];
$consulta_levantar_imagen = "SELECT `$campo` FROM `serie` WHERE `id`= $_GET[id_usuario_eli_img]";
$imagenes = mysql_query($consulta_levantar_imagen);
$imagen = mysql_fetch_array($imagenes);
$nombre_imagen = $imagen[$campo];

$consulta = "UPDATE `serie` SET  `$campo` = '' WHERE `id` = $_GET[id_usuario_eli_img]";
$borrar_img_ok = mysql_query($consulta);
unlink("../publico/img/".$nombre_imagen);

if($borrar_img_ok){
    header("Location:listado.php?editado=ok");
}
```

Comment: Where is `actualizar_imagen` being called?

Comment: The $_POST[id_editar] shouldn't it need to be inside `{}` brackets?

Comment: maiorano84: right below the function, like this: `$poster = actualizar_imagen('poster');`

Comment: Alejandro Iván: I'm not sure, but so far is working without those brackets so I guess tahts not the problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "but that means that the else is not working"? Why do you expect the else-part is being called?

Comment: Peter van der Wal: Because if I have no images in my table, then `$_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name']` is suposed to be empty, therefore the else statement should be called. Something is broken in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely trying to do is the following:

```
function actualizar_imagen($imagen_cargada) {
    global $imagen;

    if ($imagen[$imagen_cargada] != '') {
        // If no value in the database
        $imagen_actual = $imagen[$imagen_cargada];
        unlink("../publico/img/".$imagen_actual);
    }

    // Following part can be outside if-statement, because you call it
    // wheter the image already exists or not
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $imagen_final = $fecha . $_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['tmp_name'], '../publico/img/' . $imagen_final);

    return $imagen_final;
}
```

What you currently have is

```
if ($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'] != "") {
     // If the name of the uploaded file is not empty
     unlink(...);
}
```

Comment: That was a bingo, but instead of `$imagen[$imagen_cargada] != ''` I needed to write `$_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'] != ''`. Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't: you need to delete the file currently in the database, right? So you need to check if there is an actual value in your database. The values in your database are stored in the $imagen-array, so you need to check that array, not the $_FILES-array.

Comment: That has a lot of sense, but when I write it as you say it automatically adds values to all other images fields in my database when they're suposed to stay empty, why's that?

Comment: I have no idea, the code you posted here doesn't update your the database (I don't see an UPDATE-query).

Comment: I just added a new part to my question, can you help me Peter?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how these two parts work together. I don't see where your function gets called, where the result of your function is used and last part uses totally different variables. So I have no idea why it would update multiple values (other than that someone is SQL-injecting your site what is pretty easily in the code you provided).